# Uber jar not found in Kubernetes via spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, sbt, sbt-assembly, spark-submit

I have a very simple Spark job, but I can't get it to work in Kubernetes. The error I get is:

```
>     19/10/03 14:59:51 WARN DependencyUtils: Local jar /opt/spark/work-dir/target/scala-2.11/ScalaTest-assembly-1.0.jar does
> not exist, skipping.
>     19/10/03 14:59:51 WARN SparkSubmit$$anon$2: Failed to load ScalaTest.
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ScalaTest
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:806)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

**Project structure:**

```
project/build.properties
project/plugins.sbt
src/main/scala/ScalaTest.scala
Dockerfile
build.sbt
```

**`build.properties`**

```
sbt.version=1.2.8
```

**`plugins.sbt`**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.10.0-RC1")
```

**`ScalaTest.scala`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object ScalaTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ScalaTest").config("spark.master", "local[*]").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    println("hello")

  }
}
```

**`Dockerfile`** This is just a wrapper image based on the one built from the kubernetes folder within Spark binaries. Before building this image I make sure I run **`sbt assembly`**, which generates the Uber jar.

```
FROM spark:latest

WORKDIR /opt/spark/work-dir

COPY target/scala-2.11/ScalaTest-assembly-1.0.jar target/scala-2.11/ScalaTest-assembly-1.0.jar
```

**`build.sbt`**

```
name := "ScalaTest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

val sparkVersion = "2.4.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % sparkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % sparkVersion % "provided"
)
```

Finally my **`spark-submit`**. Before I do this I pushed the image to ECR's registry, so EKS can pull that image. I also point to the location of the uber jar **within** my image.

```
~/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://{K8S_ENDPOINT}:443 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name test-job \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image={ECR_IMAGE}:latest \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.submission.waitAppCompletion=false \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=test-job \
    --class ScalaTest \
    local:///opt/spark/work-dir/target/scala-2.11/ScalaTest-assembly-1.0.jar
```

Also note, when I run the command below (spark-submit within my container, locally) it works as expected:

```
docker run --rm -it my-custom-image ../bin/spark-submit target/scala-2.11/ScalaTest-assembly-1.0.jar
```

**UPDATE**
Inspecting the assembled uber jar, I can see ScalaTest's class is there.

```
jar tf target/scala-2.11/ScalaTest-assembly-1.0.jar

...
ScalaTest$.class
ScalaTest.class
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is to leave the jar not in the working dir but in the jars folders. I haven't looked at the docs but probably this is an environment variable that can be changed. In any case, the Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM spark:latest

COPY target/scala-2.11/ScalaTest-assembly-1.0.jar /ops/spark/jars/ScalaTest-assembly-1.0.jar
```

And then change the `spark-submit` accordingly:

```
~/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://{K8S_ENDPOINT}:443 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name test-job \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image={ECR_IMAGE}:latest \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.submission.waitAppCompletion=false \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=test-job \
    --class ScalaTest \
    local:///opt/spark/jars/ScalaTest-assembly-1.0.jar
```